# function(s) to encode or decode &#x2714; in JAVASCRIPT ONLY no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, decode, encode

Maybe a repeated question, but here is the code.

In my last validation function

```
for(i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(checkBoxes.item(i).innerHTML == ?){
        flag[i] = "t";
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in the top small time checkings/user feedback

```
if(usn.length == 10){
    usne.innerHTML = "&#x2716;";
}
else{
    usne.innerHTML = "&#x2714;";    
}
```

What should i replace the question mark with to get `encode(innerHTML) == "&#x2714;"`

because right now im getting ✔ as it is. i want to compare it as `& # x 2 7 1 6 ;`

Comment: Because you haven't shown any research effort.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare the `innerHTML`? Just use the `.innerText`. Also, why did the escape sequence `&#x2714;` not work?

Comment: ok, i didnt know and not try innertext. plus when i used alert(innerHTML) it showed the checkmark not the code. now ill try innertext.

Comment: what should i research? is there any other forum or website or whatever where they entertain noob questions? please point me that way  and i promise i wont bother you ELITE persons ever again

Comment: OH yeah, the reason i didn't try inner text was because there is not innerText autocomplete in Dreamviewer.

Comment: innerText works thanks a lot. Here is your research value, why isn't there innerText in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\u2716` to compare the symbol.